Unit test of a class calling a singleton in C++ googletest
I have a method of a class that I want to test. The method calls the a singleton method that inside calls a method of the singleton member. I've mocked the class of the singleton member in this way:
#include "json.hpp"

using json = nlohmann::json;

class MockedUtil
{
    public:
    MockedUtil(){};
    ~MockedUtil(){};
    MOCK_METHOD(bool, readJSONFile, (const std::string &filePath, json &j));
};

and then defined the singleton as:
class MyTest_mockfunctioncall_Test;
class ConcreteSingleton : public Singleton<ConcreteSingleton>
{
private:
  FRIEND_TEST(::MyTest, mockfunctioncall);
  std::string private_key;

public:
  ConcreteSingleton(token){};
  MockedUtil wrapper;
  bool readJSON(const std::string& settings, json& my_json)
  {
    json my_json = nullptr;
    const std::string path{"MyJson.json"};
    bool result =
        wrapper.readJSONFile(path, my_json);
    if (!result)
    {
        std::cout<<"Unable to read. Failed\n";
        return false;
    }
    if (!my_json[this->private_key].contains(settings))
    {
        std::cout<<"Setting is not present in my_json\n";
        std::cout<< my_json.dump(1, '\t') << "\n\n";
        return false;
    }
    my_json[settings] = my_json[this->private_key][settings];
    return true;
  }
};

You see that the singleton inside has a member of type MockedUtil that is being used inside the function readJSON.
The member function I want to test is like:
class ClassToBeTested{
  public:
  ClassToBeTested() = default;
  
  ~ClassToBeTested() = default;
  void foo()
  {
    int value = -1;
    json my_json = nullptr;
    std::cout<<" before calling\n";
    const std::string{"my_key"};
    bool result = ConcreteSingleton::get().readJSON(key,my_json);
    if(result){
        value = my_json[key];
        std::cout<<"LINE COVERED\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"LINE NOT COVERED\n";
    }
  }
};

Finally my test looks like:
TEST(MyTest, mockfunctioncall)
{
  auto& singleton = ConcreteSingleton::get();
  ClassToBeTested object;
  json my_json = nullptr;
  const std::string mystr{"MyJson"};
  ON_CALL(
    singleton.wrapper,
    readJSONFile(::testing::Ref(mystr), ::testing::Ref(my_json)))
    .WillByDefault(
      [&](const std::string& filePath, json& j)
      {
        std::cout<<"inside lambda\n";
        j = json::parse(R"(
          {
            "MyKey": 1
          }
        )");
        return true;
      });
  object.foo();
}

I was expecting that the lambda function gets executed here, that it would return true when the mocked function is called and that the second parameter passed by reference would get populated, so that the line std::cout<<"LINE COVERED\n"; is run and when trying to access the json object by key no exception is thrown.
The series of prints I get is:
before calling
Setting is not present
{
        "MyKey": null
}
LINE NOT COVERED

The lambda function is not executed. I would like to execute it so that the result of the mock function would return true and the parameter passed by reference would get populated.
Is it possible to do that in gtest?
NOTe
I am asking this question because I cannot do dependency injection.
Also this is a dimplified version of the originale code which can be posted here for seek of brevity.

Your ON_CALL setup is wrong because you're using ::testing::Ref. You should use ::testing::_ for wildcards unless you have a very specific reason not to. This will match any argument.

::testing::Ref means "only use this default if the function is called with this exact object as argument". Obviously, it cannot happen because  these objects are not passed to unit under test anyhow.

If I use ::testing::_, would the parameter passed by reference be populated so that in the foo() it is not empty?

You confuse two mechanisms. Matchers like testing::Ref and testing::_ are only used to determine if the call is correct (in case of EXPECT_CALL) or if the call should be dispatched to given default (in case of ON_CALL). What happens to those arguments is only controlled with Actions (like your lambda here).

Even if I do ON_CALL(     singleton.wrapper,     readJSONFile(::testing::_, ::testing::_)) the lambda is not being called

Design rule one for unit testable code : No singletons, use dependency injection

@PepijnKramer I know this is not a best practice and if it were my code I would change it but can't, so your comment does not help at all.

@roschach That information was missing in your question. And other people may benefit from it. So my apologies if you didn't find it helpful. It was not personal

You don't need any matchers in your ON_CALL, just the readJSONFile(_, _)) will do the job; Or readJSONFile(mystr, _) to catch only calls with specific str. Your lambda will already get the arguments passed by your system under test (in this case my_json by reference).

But, what is more important, you are writing production code that is dependent on the tests, which should be a no-go. Instead, go for dependency injection, e.g. void foo(IJsonReader* reader) { ... reader->readJSONFile(... , mock the abstract interface, and for the concrete implementation you can use your singleton pattern.

@pptaszni as said in my previous comment "Even if I do ON_CALL(     singleton.wrapper,     readJSONFile(::testing::, ::testing::)) the lambda is not being called"

@pptaszni this is not the real code, its not in production, i simplified it to be meaningful, understandable a and compact as much as possible

If it's not the real code (I mean as real as reasonably possible), then it is hard to write a real answer. I took your example, corrected whatever was needed (you didn't provide the code of Singleton, there are compilation errors, I had to assume that instance of ConcreteSingleton is global), used the testing::_ placeholders, then compiled and run the test. And guess what? The lambda was called, and the referenced my_json was populated. Hence my suggestions.
